# I can access my database with django and query it with objects.get() but objects.filter() will not work

Tags: django

I am just making a simple website as I am learning django.

I have a view function that looks like this:

```
  def vieworkout(request):
        date= datetime.today()
        obj = userworkouts.objects.filter(userid=52)
        date = request.POST['date']
        
        
        
        
        context = {
            'exercise': obj.exercise
        }
    
        return render(request, 'clientIndex.html', context)
```

when I use userworkouts.object.get() I can pass the exercise object no problem. When I change it to filter I get an error, "'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'exercise'". Does anyone know why this is happening?

Answer (score 1):

Because the .get returns a single object and the .filter returns a list like object. You have to grab the first result.

Try this:

```
obj = userworkouts.objects.filter(userid=52).first()
```

If you want to render the entire collection, don't use first and pass the entire list into your template:

```
def vieworkout(request): 
    workouts=userworkouts.objects.filter(userid=52)
    return render(request, 'clientIndex.html', { 'workouts': workouts })
```

In your template you can iterate through the workouts and dot into each object's properties.

Comment: I see, I want to pass all the object that match 52 to my html page. How do I change the context to include multiple objects?

Comment: Just pass in obj and iterate over the collection in your template.

Comment: But if I use first() I'm only getting one object. Sorry I am new at this

Comment: Don't use first. Pass in the whole queryset.